# Cannot send email using SwiftMailer

Tags: php, ubuntu, swiftmailer

I am trying to send email, with the following php code, using SwiftMailer.

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.domain.com', 25);
$transport->setUsername(getenv('USER_NAME'));
$transport->setPassword(getenv('PASSWORD'));
$swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$mail = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$mail->setSubject('Hello');
$mail->setFrom(array('sender@domain.com' => 'Sender Name' ));
$mail->setTo(array('receiver@domain.com' => 'Receiver Name'));
$mail->setBody('some message');

$result = $swift->send($mail, $failures);

if ($result)
{
    echo "Message successfully sent!";
}
else
{
    echo "There was an error:\n";
    print_r($failures);
}
```

the following error is coming ...

> There was an error:
>
> Array ( [0] => receiver@domain.com )

I am using Mandrill as SMTP ...

Comment: Regarding the doc, the problem come from your smtp. It rejects this recipient. As @Sergey Kornilov says, use a real mail instead.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use real email addresses instead of receiver@domain.com and sender@domain.com.

Another thing - you may need to set SMTP server, username and password in order to send emails from your server.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable name does not yet exist, it will be initialized as an empty array and then failures will be added to that array.                                                       If the variable already exists it will be type-cast to an array and failures will be added to it.

Comment: There is no gain to add this description here since it belong to the doc for the [Failures By-reference](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#getting-failures-by-reference).